# Latex on a .txt file 

Tags: parsing, latex, text-parsing, tex

Is it possible to use Latex for scientific formulas (mathematic, physic, chemistry) that are written on a .txt file ?

example about a chemistry formule

```
\[
  HC \equiv CH + H_{2}O
  \cto{Hg^{++}}{18\%\ H_{2}SO_{4},\ 90^\circ}{14} 
  CH_{3}-CHO
\]
```

I have no ideas to do it.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Do you want to create a list of images (one for each of the formulas), convert your text file in another format, get some chemical formula information?

Comment: I want to create scientific mcq  (with formulas) by using a .txt file because i'll import this .txt file to do it. and instead of writting these formulas on a form, i want to do it on a .txt file. i want the corrrect formulas relateed to the correct mcq. example : http://chemistry.boisestate.edu/people/richardbanks/organic/mc/vol2/mcquestions317b.htm where i have mixed between txt, images and formulas(compiled as images).

Answer (score 1):

Save it as a `.tex` file instead of a `.txt` file. You'll need to install LaTeX (possibly with some chemistry packages too - they are several packages for typesetting chemisty. You can search for packages [on CTAN](http://ctan.org/).). Walk yourself through [some examples](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how%20to%20latex).

Comment: thank you, in fact i have to parse a txt file who build a mcq items, i will have the mcq and i need scientific formulas inside (for scientific mcq)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340038/about-importing-txt-files-how-much-size-or-delimiter-can-i-set

Comment: oh ok soi have to parse a file with .tex extension and put everything as a latex document?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do. LaTex is used most commonly to produce postscript or PDF files. It compiles a .tex file and produces a document. I use LaTex for entire documents, not just single formulas. Perhaps you can extract the LaTex code from your .txt, save it as a .tex, compile it, and then use the image, but why not just skip the .txt and go straight to LaTex?

Comment: because i don't know the correct way to do it.  i was thinking to parse a .txt file to extract the data i need, but i totally forget that i can build chemistry mcq. so i have to extract the Latex code, save, compile, use the image .. but how i will put the image on the correct mcq ?

Comment: Probably you'll name the tex file something like "mcq1.tex", and get an image that is "mcq1.pdf".